# Concatenating sublists with ":"

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to build a string using ":" and then write that string to a file. 
Function gets two lists that include strings, which are amounts of money

```
[["$123,123,123", "$68,656", "$993,993,993,993", "$123,141,142,142"],
 ["$60", "$800,600", "$700,600,500", "$20,200,200,201"]]
```

It should be written as

```
"$123,123,123":"$68,656":"$993,993,993,993":"$123,141,142,142"
"$60":"$800,600":"$700,600,500":"$20,200,200,201"
```

Currently I have something like this:

```
def save_amount (amount, moneys):
    with open (moneys, "w") as file:
        for i in amount:
            moneys_s = str(i)
```

How to proceed?

Comment: You need to flatten the list of lists and then join on ":" rather than splitting

Comment: You are missing two `"` in the original data: `"$60"`.

Comment: Question title says, split with ":" but your question body says the opposite.

Comment: Is this not a case for the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) module? It looks like a dialect with delimiter=':' and quoting=QUOTE_ALL.

Answer (score 2):

First flatten the list and then use `join`, Use list comprehension here :

```
>>> [ ':'.join('"' + j + '"' for j in i) for i in l ]
['"$123,123,123":"$68,656":"$993,993,993,993":"$123,141,142,142"',
'"$60":"$800,600":"$700,600,500":"$20,200,200,201"']
```

Comment: This does not fit the description, the `"` around each sublist are missing.

Comment: For more details on flatting lists see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: The `Good artists copy, Great artists steal` in your dev story works great with your profile picture!

Comment: user needs output in multi-line

Comment: @moritzg nice observation, I admire Martijn Pieters, he is inspiration

Answer (score 1):

```
'"' + '":"'.join( str(j) for i in money for j in i) + '"'
```

where money is your list of lists

Comment: user needs output in multi-line

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [["$123,123,123", "$68,656", "$993,993,993,993", "$123,141,142,142"],
     ["$60", "$800,600", "$700,600,500", "$20,200,200,201"]]
[ ':'.join('"' + j + '"' for j in i) for i in l ]
```

Output:

```
['"$123,123,123":"$68,656":"$993,993,993,993":"$123,141,142,142"',
 '"$60":"$800,600":"$700,600,500":"$20,200,200,201"']
```